# Join language specific names in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Given the following tables:

**Materials**

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
|Material         |Name             |
+-----------------------------------+
|00000001         |Material Number 1|
|00000002         |Material Number 2|
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**Material Names**

```
+---------+---------+-------------+
|Material |Language |Name         |
+---------------------------------+
|00000001 |DE       |Mat. Nummer 1|
|00000001 |FR       |Matérial 1   |
|00000002 |SP       |Mat. 1       |
+---------+---------+-------------+
```

How can I create an SQL statement (MSSQL 2005 Flavor) that will return the data as follows:

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+
|Material |Name_EN        |Name_DE        |Name_FR   |Name_SP   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|00000001 |Material Number|1 Mat. Nummer 1|Matérial 1|NULL      |
|00000002 |Material Number|2 NULL         |NULL      |Mat. 1    |
+---------+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+
```

I tried several approaches using `CASE WHEN`, `IS NOT NULL`, and the like. But it always resulted in single rows where only one column was filled, even if there were more names available for a material.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: are these languages fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `join` and conditional aggregation:

```
select m.materialid, m.name as Name_EN,
       max(case when nm.language = 'DE' then nm.name end) as Name_DE,
       max(case when nm.language = 'FR' then nm.name end) as Name_FR,
       max(case when nm.language = 'SP' then nm.name end) as Name_SP
from materials m join
     materialnames nm
     on m.materialid = nm.materialid
group by m.materialid, m.name;
```